# How do I create a ComboField in Django forms (which accepts CharField and ChoiceField inputs)?

Tags: django

I have to create a ComboField in Django forms which accepts CharField and ChoiceField inputs. Is there a way to do it in forms.py? Or should I use javascript /html to do it?

Comment: Combofields are use to validate user inputs. I think what you are looking for is ChoiceField. Can you be more elaborate with model.

Comment: This might be useful:  https://github.com/mlavin/django-selectable